# I try to make the merge sort go from bigger to little but it keep going from little to big

Tags: java, mergesort, helper, jgrasp

Trying to get it from big to little I'm trying to use the Sort & Search Merge Sort:

```
import java.util.*;

class MergeSorter {
   public static void sort(int[] a) {  
      if (a.length <= 1) { return; }
      int[] first = new int[a.length / 2];
      int[] second = new int[a.length - first.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) { 
         first[i] = a[i]; 
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < second.length; i++) { 
         second[i] = a[first.length + i]; 
      }
      sort(first);
      sort(second);
      merge(first, second, a);
   }

   private static void merge(int[] first, int[] second, int[] a) {  
      int iFirst = 0;
      int iSecond = 0;
      int j = 0;

      while (iFirst < first.length && iSecond < second.length) {  
         if (first[iFirst] < second[iSecond]) {  
            a[j] = first[iFirst];
            iFirst++;
         } else {  
            a[j] = second[iSecond];
            iSecond++;
         }
         j++;
      }
      while (iFirst < first.length) { 
         a[j] = first[iFirst]; 
         iFirst++; j++;
      }
      while (iSecond < second.length) { 
         a[j] = second[iSecond]; 
         iSecond++; j++;
      }
   }
}

public class MergeSortDemo888888 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int [] myAry = { 3, 2, 6, 7 };
      System.out.println("myAry is " + Arrays.toString(myAry));
      MergeSorter.sort(myAry);
      System.out.println("myAry is sorted descendingly using selection sort: "+Arrays.toString(myAry));
   }
}
```

Comment: Try to dry run the code on the array you have chosen as example and see why it is sorting from little to big. Have a closer look at the `merge` function. Some reference to help: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first `if` in the `merge` function just change this `(first[iFirst] < second[iSecond])` into this `(first[iFirst] > second[iSecond])`.

Comment: OMG thanks alot im a new to coding and this had me going crazy

Comment: hey it you dont mind looking at my second question having a problem with it

Comment: Where's your 2nd question?

Comment: using the LinkedList<Integer> Decare a number n = 1279.
4. The sample output:
 The number is 1729
 1, 7, 2, 9,